# Bugged BottomSheet which is shown when not required

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a BottomSheet in my App whic have to be shown ONLY at the BottomAppBar navigation button click.

The issue is that in my BottomAppBar i have a FAB button which handles a long click which shows a View and a FAB menu,
when long clicked it make even the BottomSheet expanded when there is no code for it!

Here is my BottomSheet:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the only click where i make it EXPANDED_HALF:

```
bottomAppBar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
    bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED
}
```

And here is my longClick which make it fully expanded:

```
fabNuovo.setOnLongClickListener {
   if (View.GONE == fabBGLayout.visibility) {
            showFAB()
        }else {
            closeFAB()
        }
}

private fun showFAB() {
    fabNuovo.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@LetturaActivity,R.drawable.ic_baseline_close_24))
    fabSend.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    fabBGLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    fabSend.animate().translationY(-120F)
}

private fun closeFAB() {
    fabNuovo.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@LetturaActivity,R.drawable.ic_baseline_done_24))
    fabBGLayout.visibility = View.GONE
    fabSend.visibility = View.GONE
    fabSend.animate().translationY(0f)
}
```

EDIT:

It's not expanded for really as it doesn't cast any callback in BottomSheetCallback...

[image]

And even if i click to dismiss the FAB menu it's expanded if not and collapsed if expanded...

EDIT2:

The issue is surely given from one of the following lines in showFAB and closeFAB:

```
fabSend.visibility = View.VISIBLE
fabBGLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
fabSend.animate().translationY(-120F)
```